# save result of mongodb's query in variable and get one field only from that variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

```
var std = require("./models/stdModel");
var ss=std.find({stdId:req.body.sid});
console.log(ss.stdname);
```

model have fields stdid and stdname, i want only stdname on the base of stdid which i've entered in input field.
save result in ss and then get one field from it

Answer (score 0):

```
    std.find({stdId:req.body.sid},{stdname:1});
```

Here, the second object passed to the query is of BSON format.
This query will return documents with only stdname and _id .

If you don't need _id as well

```
std.find({stdId:req.body.sid},{stdname:1,_id:0});
```

Value 1 will select those field and 0 will ignore that field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want stdname in some variable, how can i do that?

Comment: std.aggregate([
 {$project:{'newVar':'$stdname'}}
])

Answer (score 0):

This is because **.find** is an async function. You need to call **.then** method and try **console.log** inside .then function.

```
std.find({stdId:req.body.sid})
    .select('stdname')
    .exec() //this is just another way to run query.
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: on console i just get [ ] , and i want stdname in some variable i need to pass it to ejs file